# How add a circuit breaker for <int:gateway> in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Here is my code i had a gateway defined in my spring-config.xml like below

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway"
                 service-interface="com.sample.si.MyService"
                 error-channel="myError-channel"
                 default-request-channel="sendServiceChannel" 
                 >
        <int:method name="sendService" request-channel="sendServiceChannel" /
```

When i debug my test it is directly going to RequesthandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice.class and never going to my error channel, below is my error channel

```
<int:channel id="myError-channel">

</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="myError-channel">
    <int:service-activator ref="myErrorHandler" method="resolveError" />
</int:chain>
```

I want to redirect to error channel when i had an exception from gateway and want to redirect every message to error channel with the circuitbreaker halfopen timelimit. Any help is appreciated

Edit Showing Outbound gateway

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="sendMyService"
                         uri="${my.gateway.send.uri}"
                         mapped-request-headers="*"
                         marshaller="SOAPMarshaller"
                         unmarshaller="SOAPMarshaller"
                         message-sender="soapMessageSender"
                         request-channel="sendServiceChannel"
                         fault-message-resolver="faultResolver"
                         reply-channel="sendServiceResponseChannel">


<int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice">
            <property name="threshold" value="1" />
            <property name="halfOpenAfter" value="10000" />
        </bean>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

I want the circuit breaker between the  and  so that i dont want to hit the outbound gateway when the provided uri in the outbound gateway is not available, thanks for looking in to it [Gary Russell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell)

Here is my testcase

```
public class EmailGatewayProducerConsumerTest {

@Inject
@Qualifier("myGateway")
private Myservice myService;

@Test
public void senderTest(){
MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest(12,"rajendra","rajednra.ch@hotmail.com");
           try {
        myService.sendService(myRequest);
    }catch (Exception e){
        //System.out.println("Caught Exception " +e);
    }
}
```

}

The error handler is a sending the exception message to queue and reading it back and sending again to gateway here is my error handler code

```
public class ErrorHandler{@Inject private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
     public void resolveError( Message<MessagingException> message) {
         try{ 
             MyRequest myRequest=(MessageRequest)message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload()
             jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(DATA_QUEUE, myRequest);
        } catch(Exception e){
    //log error
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is my consumer which consumes it and sends back to the gateway

```
 @JmsListener(destination = DATA_QUEUE)public void consume(MyRequest myRequest) throws InterruptedException {
log.info("Receiving  event: {}", myRequest);
try {
   myService.sendService(myRequest)
}catch (Exception e){
    log.error(e.toString());
} }
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connect to localhost:10002 timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:10002 timed out
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561)
at org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:81)
at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:188)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.execute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:74)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice.java:61)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:117)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
... 90 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The gateway (and hence error channel) is downstream of your circuit breaker - you need to show what's upstream of (before) the service-activator - that's where you need to configure the error-channel to handle the circuit-breaker result.

That said, you have a circular dependency here - the gateway is sending to the service-activator, which is invoking the gateway again.

You need to explain further what you are trying to do - show more config - upstream and downstream.

**EDIT**

Bear in mind that will cause an infinite loop because the failed message will be retried indefinitely.

Sending to JMS should not make any different compared to this test case, which works exactly as I would expect (including the infinite loop)...

```
public interface GW {

    void send(String foo);

}


<int:gateway id="gw" service-interface="com.example.GW" default-request-channel="foo"
    error-channel="errorChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="foo" expression = "1 / 0"> <!-- always fail -->
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice">
            <property name="threshold" value="1" />
            <property name="halfOpenAfter" value="10000" />
        </bean>
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>

<int:bridge input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="retryChannel" />

<int:channel id="retryChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="retryChannel">
    <int:transformer expression="payload.failedMessage.payload" />
    <int:service-activator ref="gw" />
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" />
</int:chain>
```

Result:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: 1 / 0;
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

CircuitBreakerOpenException: Circuit Breaker is Open for ServiceActivator for [ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor for: [1 / 0]] 

CircuitBreakerOpenException: Circuit Breaker is Open for ServiceActivator for [ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor for: [1 / 0]] 

CircuitBreakerOpenException: Circuit Breaker is Open for ServiceActivator for [ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor for: [1 / 0]]
```

Comment: Can you please loot in to it when you got some time, edited with the outbound gateway, Thanks!!

Comment: As I said, your configuration is all wrong `default-request-channel="sendServiceChannel"` sends a message to the `<service-activator/>` which invokes the gateway again. You also have the ws outbound gateway subscribed to the same channel. The service activator needs to be subscribed to some other channel which gets messages from some upstream component.

Comment: I moved my circuit breaker to outbound gateway as shown above, now it is working to some extent, when the timeout exception comes it is redirecting to error channel and changing the state of circuit breaker to open, but if i'm immediately trying to send the message to outbound gateway from errorhandler with in less than halfopenafter timelimit , it is not supposed to hit the URI right? but still i'm getting the timeout exception (had a debug point on WebServiceIOException class) and then again going back to errorchannel[Garry Russell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell)

Comment: Is the exception explicitly thrown by circuit breaker or the circuit breaker is not working ? i'm testing using a testcase.

Comment: You need to show your test case - edit the question.

Comment: Added my simple testcase

Comment: You need to show the whole thing including the error handler code.

Comment: Added my error handler which acts like a producer to a queue and sends its to the queue, and consumer @jmslistener listens to it and sends the message to the gateway, which should return back to error handler when the circuit breaker is stil open without hitting the gateway

Comment: See the example in my edit - works exactly as I would expect.

Comment: In the above edit case it is failing at the expression ='1/0', what i'm supposed to replace the expression with so the effect is on outbound gateway, I wanted the circuitbreaker in between so that when the Circuitbrekaer is open itshould not hit the outbound gateway URI

Comment: That is just simulating your WS failure; it behaves exactly the same. The retry gets the circuit breaker open exception and not the / 0. In your case it will get that exception instead of invoking the web service.

Comment: Thanks Gary For you time, so in my case circuit breaker itself is throwing the timeout exception without hitting the outbound when it is open? okay i will retest it and see what I'm missing Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Gary, One more question, I added my exception above , I'm not getting the log for CircuitBreaker Open is my configuration wrong in this case? is that the right way to do it ? totally confused [Gary Russell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell)

Comment: I assume this is on the retry. Are you sure the retry is going to the same web service endpoint instance? It's impossible to get to this line `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice.java:61` if the threshold has been reached and the `halfOpenAfter` has not elapsed. I suggest you use a debugger to figure out what's going on and/or run with DEBUG logging and follow the message flow.

Comment: Thanks Gary, It Worked its the halfOpenAfter timelimit i had 10000 and changed it to 60000.

Comment: Hy gary, I'm looking a way to write test cases for inbound gateway and outbound gateway and errorchannel to test the flow can you please direct me to some resource where i can find examples on how to write test cases for those. Thanks!!

Comment: There are some testing examples [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/testing-examples) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/advanced-testing-examples). Also see chapter 18 of [Spring Integration in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-integration-in-action).

Answer (score 0):

Above is my edited configuration that worked for me to implement the circuit breaker, after all the changes I still had this issue with halfOpenAfter time, which I increased to **60000** and it worked the above solution in the question should work for circuit breaker, follow the comment of me and Gary Russell.